# Stop touch interaction when animation sequence is running cocos2d for iphone

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, sequence

Is there a way to stop touch interaction when animation sequence is running. Animation sequence is load from ccbi file.

```
    CCBAnimationManager* animationManager = self.userObject;
    [animationManager runAnimationsForSequenceNamed:@"Blink"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what interaction do you want to stop.

If it is a CCLayer, then set `layer.touchEnabled = NO;` and it will stop receiving touches. If it is your custom UI component, then you have to manually remove the touch delegate from it and add it when the animation ends.

Don't forget that you can set `animationManager.delegate = self` to get a callback when the animation finishes, so you can enable the touches again.

Comment: - (void) completedAnimationSequenceNamed:(NSString *)name
{
    if ([name isEqualToString:@"Fly"]) {
        self.touchEnabled = YES;
    }
    
}
I have used above code for touch enable again, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Because the animations have different names? :D

Comment: I used above code with [animationManager runAnimationsForSequenceNamed:@"Fly"];